# Auto Prediction Register model update Issue in RAL

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to understand the auto prediction concept in UVM RAL model,
and I came across the Auto Prediction Register model update Issue in https://youtu.be/hrxhUE_RHyY?t=145. But, I didn't understand "UVC sequences which access registers will not update the model".

How the Implicit Prediction can't update the register model or something not?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of sequences that can write to a register:

1. A sequence which uses RAL methods, such as `write` and `update`.  These are shown as `regseq1` in the above diagram.
2. A sequence which does **not** use RAL methods.  These are shown as `uvcseq1` in the above diagram.

This article shows a [predictor](https://www.chipverify.com/uvm/register-environment#predictor) to demonstrate the difference:

> However, it is not required to always use the register model to write
> into the design as individual sequences with address and data can be
> started on the same target agent to write into design registers. This
> would make the values in the register model stale, and would require
> an update every time some other sequence reads or writes into the
> design.

Keep in  mind that it is not *mandatory* to use a RAL register model in a testbench.  The UVC on its own is capable of driving read and write transactions to the DUT.

Comment: That depends on the circumstance that I use RAL register model in a testbench. What if no needs the RAL model in UVC, we even do not expect that RAL model update. But You  said there are two types of sequences that we can read/write to a register, then what usage can I expect that I can read/write to a register without RAL methods?

Comment: @Carter: The RAL model instance is placed in the env.  It is not an instance within any UVC (agent).